# Webgl vertex position Built in VertexShader

Tags: javascript, webgl

I only use the matrix to draw a square! Only the matrix is updated in each rendering. How to remove Vertex Position from my codes

lock like this
https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-drawing-without-data.html

```
#version 300 es
in vec4 a_position;
in vec2 a_texcoord;
uniform mat4 u_matrix;
out vec2 v_texcoord;
void main() 
    ngl_Position = u_matrix * a_position;
    v_texcoord = a_texcoord;
}
```

and remove this

```
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
0, 0, 0,
0, 1, 0,
1, 0, 0,
0, 1, 0,
1, 1, 0,
1, 0, 0]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
```

Sorry for using Google Translator

Comment: I wrote only the part of the code that does not cause confusion

Answer (score 0):

Here is your square vertex shader. You don't need to use a matrix.

```
#version 300 es

void main() {
  float xs[6] = float[](0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
  float ys[6] = float[](0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
  float x = xs[gl_VertexID];
  float y = ys[gl_VertexID];
  gl_Position = vec4(x, y, 0, 1);
}
```

And to render you just do this. You don't need to do any bufferData or any uniforms.

```
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
```

Comment: I am need draw many objects with matrix to make a game